# How to get element from (array) where return type Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

Currently in order to get first element in the tableRows ->  return type TransactionsPage.tableRows: `Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>` i am doing the following

```
TransactionsPage.tableRows.first().click();
```

There also isnt a way to just do `const a = TransactionsPage.tableRows[0]` since the return type, or there is a way ? if not please let me know whats the best option as if i want to grab with element i do not want to iterate through each one to get there.

Comment: What does `TransactionsPage.tableRows` translate into?

Comment: i just posted another question cold you check there @AlapanDas thank you